# An application of the method of Nehari Manifold

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

In what follows, I transcribe an example that illustrates the application of the Nehari Manifold method to solve a nonlinear partial differential equation contained in the text (in Portuguese) that I am reading.

My question is: Why can we conclude that $\Phi(u) \geq 0$ in the proof of Lemma 1.2 below?

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^N$ be an smooth, bounded, connected open set. Consider the following problem:

$$
(*)\begin{cases}
- \Delta u = f(u) \quad \text{ in } \Omega \\
u = 0 \quad \text{ on } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
Assume that the nonlinearity $f$ satisfies the following:

($f_1$) $f$ is of class $C^1$ and there exist $C, r \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $2 < r < 2^*$ and 
\begin{equation}
|f(t)| \leq C(1 + |t|^{r-1}); \qquad (1)
\end{equation}

($f_2$) $\displaystyle \lim_{|t| \to 0} \frac{|f(t)|}{|t|} = 0$;

($f_3$) $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to + \infty} \frac{F(t)}{t^2} = + \infty$ where $F(t) = \int_0^tf(s) ds$;

($f_4$) The map $\displaystyle t \mapsto \frac{f(t)}{t}$ is increasing for $t > 0$.

By ($f_1$) and ($f_2$), given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that 
$$
|f(t)| \leq \varepsilon |t| + C_\varepsilon |t|^{r-1}.
$$

> **Theorem**: If ($f_1$) - ($f_4$) hold, then $(*)$ has a Ground State solution.

A weak solution to $(*)$ is $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that 
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla \phi dx - \int_\Omega f(u)\phi dx \quad \forall \phi \in H_0^1(\Omega),
$$
that is, if it is a critical point of the functional 
$$
\Phi(u) = \frac12 ||u||^2 - \int_\Omega F(u) dx
$$
where $||\cdot||$ is the usual norm in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

The Nehari manifold is the set
$$
\mathcal{N} = \{u \in H_0^1(\Omega) \setminus \{0\} \ : \ \Phi'(u)u = 0 \}
$$

The Nehari manifold is not empty:

> **Lemma 1.1:** If ($f_1$) - ($f_4$) hold, then for $u \in H_0^1(\Omega) \setminus \{0\}$ there exists a unique $t_0 = t_0(u) > 0$ such that $t_0u \in \mathcal{N}$ and $\Phi(t_0u) = \max_{t \geq 0}\Phi(tu)$.

I get the proof of this lemma so I will omit it here. I can add it upon requests.

> **Lemma 1.2:** There exists a constant $C >0$ such that 
>   $$
> 0 < C < ||u|| \quad \forall u \in \mathcal{N}.
> $$
>   Also, for all $u \in \mathcal{N}$ we have that $\Phi(u) \geq 0$.
>
> *Proof:* By $(1)$ and the Sobolev immersions, for $u \in \mathcal{N}$ we have: 
>   $$
> ||u||^2 = \int_\Omega f(u)u \ dx \leq \varepsilon C_1 ||u||^2 + C_\varepsilon C_2 ||u||^r
> $$
>   and hence
>   $$
> 0 < \left(\frac{1 - \varepsilon C_1}{C_\varepsilon C_2} \right)^{1/(r-2)} \leq ||u||.
> $$
>   Now, from ($f_4$) we have that 
>   $$
> f'(t)t - f(t) > 0 
> $$
>   for $t > 0$, which is equivalent to the function
>   $$
> \frac12 f(t)t - F(t)
> $$
>   being increasing for $t > 0$. From this, we conclude that 
>   $$
> \Phi(u) = \Phi(u) - \frac12 \Phi'(u)u  = \int_\Omega \left(\frac12 f(u)u - F(u)\right) dx \geq 0
> $$